# 2013Q4 Intel Graphics Stack Release - how to install

Tags: ubuntu, intel-graphics

I think that the new 2013Q4 Intel Graphics Stack Release will help my Lenovo Yoga 2 drivers with sleeping the graphics card.

Do I have to install all of the parts separatley, is there a tutorial to do this somewhere? Or is there a script installer?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to install it?

Comment: yes but do i need every part?

Comment: You didn't provide a link to the download so I don't know

Comment: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/2013q4-intel-graphics-stack-release

Comment: Only a few of those downloads is the drivers.  The rest is whats required to compile the drivers on your own.  The link you provide is design for those users who have the technical skills to compile the source to the drivers, compile them, and at that point install the drivers.  I highly suspect somebody has already done that for Ubuntu depending on the version your using of course.